# Are there any sources that contain information on the airfoils of the Boeing 737-500 and 737NG Aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, airfoil

I have found some information about this on airfoiltools.com (http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=b737a-il) but it doesn't specify the exact version of the aircraft, as the generations have different wing sizes. Also, the site has information about a midspan airfoil, which part of the wing would it be located in? Any information about the winglets would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, this information is proprietary.

The public information about 737 foils is based on the original -100 model.

Further, it can be assumed that any modern aircraft with sufficient resources behind it utilizes custom designed airfoils that may be similar to catalog airfoils, but that are not in the catalog.